# getMonth doesnt recognize dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, google-sheets

So have my googledocs document with following 2 functions in javascript:

```
function test(date) {
 return date.getMonth()+1 
}

function hours_monthly(target_month, target_year,  date_range, hour_range) {
  r = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < date_range.length ; i++){
    if (target_month == date_range[i].getMonth() +1 && date_range[i].getYear() - 2000 == target_year ){
       r += hour_range[i]
    }
  }
  return r
}
```

So now I want to use the code. While the test function is just fine at reading the month of any given date, by assigning "= test(C9)" to cell. Where C9 is a cell which got the date of 6/9/16 assigned to it.

If use a the second funtion it says it can't find the getMonth() function of the exact same date C9 and just outputs ERROR. More precisly it says:

"can't find the getMonth() function in Tue Sept 06 2016 00:00:00 GTM +0200"

date_range is an array of dates, hour_range is an array of integers.
The problem porbably lies somewhere in the usage of arrays.

The same problem arrises when doing comparisions:

```
function test2(date1, date2) {
  if (date1 > date2) {
    return 1
  }
  else {
   return 2 
  }


function hours_period(start_date, end_date, date_range, hour_range){
  r = 0;
  t = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < date_range.length; i++){
    if ( (date_range[i] >= start_date)  && (date_range[i] <= end_date) ){
       t += 1
       r += hour_range[i] 
    }

  }
  return [t, r]
}
```

Now again the test2 function works totally fine but as soon as I feed an array (date_range) it stops working, in this case it doesnt give an ERROR instead it just outputs [0,0] no matter how many dates acutally fit the if-statement

Comment: Can you provide access to a sample file, including the script?  Make a copy of your file and replace sensitive data with test data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass date as string and string don't have getMonth method.

Fix it by wrap the date in new Date(date)

```js
function test(date) {
 // I wrap the new date you pass with new Date(date)
 return new Date(date).getMonth()+1; 
}

function hours_monthly(target_month, target_year,  date_range, hour_range) {
  r = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < date_range.length ; i++){
    if (target_month == date_range[i].getMonth() +1 && date_range[i].getYear() - 2000 == target_year ){
       r += hour_range[i]
    }
  }
  return r
}

console.log(test("6/9/16"));
```

Comment: Well, yep that solved the problem though as said the test function already work just fine.

Comment: Note that parsing of strings with the Date constructor is not recommended, you should manually parse it with a bespoke function or library.